# Principal axis length of convex hull in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is it possible to measure the principal axis length of the convex hull?
I have plotted the convex hull of an RGB image using 'convhull' and 'trisurf' commands. 'regionprops3' command can measure the region properties but only for binary images. Is there any command to measure the principal axis length of a convex hull? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please check the code below for reference.

The sample code:

```
u=double(imread('peppers.png'));
R=u(:, :, 1); G=u(:, :, 2); B=u(:, :, 3);
v=convhull(R(:),G(:),B(:));
figure, trisurf(v, R(:),G(:),B(:));
nu=normalize(u, 'range');
p=regionprops3(nu, 'PrincipalAxisLength');
```

Comment: Can you provide some code you have done at this moment?

Comment: You can find the distance between the two most distant points. Or you can compute the moments of inertia of the solid given by the convex hull, but that is quite messy in 3D I believe.

Comment: I would expect `regionprops3` to give you the correct answer if you set the vertex coordinates of the convex hull to 1 in a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: @Keikai-Code: u=imread(' a 3 channel image'); r=u(:, :, 1); g=u(:, :, 2);  b=u(:, :, 3); v=convhull(r(:), g(:), b(:)); figure, trisurf(v, r(:), g(:), b(:)).

Comment: @beaker-Can you please provide me code?

Comment: It appears you have a 3-channel image, not a 3-dimensional image. Please post your code and sample image in your question.

Comment: @beaker-Edited question as per the suggestions. Please check and kindly help

Comment: @POOJAPATIL `convhull` takes a list of points you're trying to enclose in the hull. You're passing a list of color intensities at each point in the entire image. I assume that you're trying to do something like getting the convex hull of one or more of the peppers in the image. In order to do this, you have to first detect the shape you want (probably including binarization) and then calculate the convex hull of the points in the shape. There are examples showing how to use `convhull` in the MATLAB documentation, I would suggest you read through those first.

Comment: Also, it appears that by adding the '-' immediately after a user name, you're preventing notification that you're responding. I got no notification of either of your comments and only saw them because I came back to check on the progress.

Comment: @beaker I want to calculate the principal axis length of the convex hull of a given 3-channel image. Please help me with code for the same.

Comment: Your request doesn't make any sense to me, unfortunately. I know what a convex hull is, I know what a principal axis is, but I have no idea what you mean by "the convex hull of a given 3-channel image." Until you've clarified what object you're computing the convex hull of, preferably along with an example, I don't think anyone can help you with your task.

Comment: @beaker I wanted to analyse the effects of noise and blur on the face images. Hence plotted all the intensity values using plot3 MATLAB command. When compared with original image, the noise and blurred versions of the original image are scattered widely and inorder to describe this with a measure, Am trying to create a convex hull of the plot and measure the principal axes. The major axis length will be almost similar for both original and distorted images but there will be a considerable difference in minor axis. Similar observations are found in both RGB and HSV (3-channel) color spaces.

Comment: @POOJAPATIL This clarifies your question a great deal. This information should really be in the question itself.

Comment: This brings me back to my first suggestion: rather than plot your points, I think you want to create a new 3d array the size of your colorspace (after scaling to integer values... to me it makes more sense to work with uint8 rather than double, but I don't know what kind of resolution you're after) and then set the points of the convex hull to 1 in the new array (making sure that the new array is an numberical type rather than logical, so it's interpreted as a labeled image). `regionprops3` should give you the correct answer on that 3d array.